# Calculate days to zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I’m trying to see if there is a formula that can provide for the following question.

If a tank has 120 gallons of liquid in it and loses .75 gallons per day, how many days until that tank is empty?

Ex:

- A1 entry (total number of gallons in tank)
- B1 entry (total set usage per day)
- C1 answer (A1 number will reach zero in x amount of days)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What have you tried? This is too simple, you shouldn't have difficulties finding out how to do it.

Comment: Just divide A1 by B1 you get result !!

Answer (score 0):

If this is Excel (or another spreadsheet that uses the same general syntax and standard functions), the formula

```
=FLOOR(A1/B1, 1)
```

would yield the integer day on which the tank will, at some point, run dry.

Of course the precise answer in decimal form is given by

```
=A1/B1
```

The precision may be useful, for example when the result is something like 3.8 and you decide to slightly lower consumption to make it to the fourth day before refueling.

If you provide more context it will be easier to provide a more confident reply.